# how to multiply a numerical field in count in sql

Tags: sql, count

i try to Something like this query

```
Select node.weight * count(ans.cn_gender) as count, ans.cn_gender , poll.pollname
From report.cm_marital_satisfaction ans Join
     poll_management.POLLES poll
     on ans.cn_pollId = poll.id Join
     poll_management.POSITIONS node
     on ans.cn_positionId = node.id
Where ans.cn_pollId in (113)
group by ans.cn_gender, poll.pollname
```

but i have error : ERROR:  column "node.weight" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: Select node.weight * count(ans.cn_gender) as count, ans.cn_g...
               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "node.weight" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 8

but I do not want use node.weight in GROUP BY
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sum()` instead of `count()`:

```
Select sum(node.weight) as count, ans.cn_gender, poll.pollname
From report.cm_marital_satisfaction ans Join
     poll_management.POLLES poll
     on ans.cn_pollId = poll.id Join
     poll_management.POSITIONS node
     on ans.cn_positionId = node.id
Where ans.cn_pollId in (113)
group by ans.cn_gender, poll.pollname
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of a function which have **an output** such as  "**MAX()**" or  "**MIN()**" :

```
Select (MAX(node.weight) * Count(ans.cn_gender)) as count_cn_gender, poll.pollname
       ans.cn_gender , MAX(poll.pollname) as pollname
From  report.cm_marital_satisfaction ans 
      Join poll_management.POLLES poll on ans.cn_pollId = poll.id Join 
      poll_management.POSITIONS node on ans.cn_positionId = node.id 
Where 
      ans.cn_pollId in (113)  
group by ans.cn_gender ,poll.pollname
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at using a derived table/temp table to get the COUNT(ans.cn_gender) with a foreign key, then join over to that to do your multiplication. That way, you are multiplying against a number, rather than an aggregate function.